# DuplexProxy is unable to call wcf service contract even though service is running

Tags: c#, wcf

We have wcf service which runs on net tcp binding and has call back contract.
When I try to call the service method using duplex proxy channel, getting the following error. service is running but couldn't able to connect with proxy client.

**C#**

```
this.Invoke(p => p.Subscribe(), true);

public void Invoke(Action<T> call, bool keepOpen)
{
    T proxy = GetProxy();            
    call(proxy);
}

public T GetProxy()
{
    NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding("");                   
    EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("net.tcp://" + Server + RelativeUrl), EndpointIdentity.CreateSpnIdentity(Server + "/" + Environment.MachineName));
    factory = new DuplexChannelFactory<T>(new InstanceContext(callbackInstance), binding, address);
    T proxy =  factory.CreateChannel();
    ((IClientChannel)proxy).Open(); 
    return proxy;
}
```

### **service**

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required, CallbackContract = typeof(IWorkflowChanged))]
public interface IWorkflowChangedPublisher
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
    void Subscribe();
}

public interface IWorkflowChanged
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void WorkflowChanged(WorkflowChangedEventArgs args);
}
```

Getting the following exception:

```
Server stack trace: 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.SyncDuplexRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:  

at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
at Tradar.Workflow.Service.IStatusPublisher.Subscribe()
at Tradar.Workflow.StatusMonitor.<>c.<Open>b__16_0(IStatusPublisher p) in D:\PMARepo\backoffice\Insight\Modules\Workflow\Core\StatusMonitor.cs:line 139
at Tradar.Workflow.ProxyFactory`1.Invoke(Action`1 call, Boolean keepOpen) in D:\PMARepo\backoffice\Insight\Modules\Workflow\Core\ProxyFactory.cs:line 79
```

Comment: Can you add at least the contracts, and better the code?

Comment: @StefGeysels, please take a look now.

Comment: Streamline your project and post more details about how do you host the service.
Besides, under the duplex mode, the IsOneWay of the operation is always true(or ConcurrencyMode is multiple). And the security of the NetTcpBinding is Windows, try to set up the security.
ChannelFactory<IService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding, new EndpointAddress(uri));
            factory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "administrator";
            factory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "123456";
            IService service = factory.CreateChannel();